# JAVA Как записать результат цикла for в одну переменную?

Tags: java, for

Можно ли результат выполнения цикла for(например на сравнение) присвоить одной переменной, чтобы дальше уже работать со значением этой переменнйо вне цикла.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            int max=1;
            int a = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
            if (a>max) max = a;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А что мешает? Наверное, только область видимости переменной, локальной для блока в скобках. Вынесите её объявление выше, и она будет доступна после окончания блока. Пример для `max`

```
   int max=1;
   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        if (a>max) max = a;
        }
   system.out.println(max);
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, разобрался.